# Ubuntu is unable to boot after enroll MOK. Error Message: EFI MOK var config table is not valid

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

I was trying to use virtual box in my local machine and then I was informed that I need to sign the kernel to continue using Virtualbox. After googling I follow this:

https://gist.github.com/reillysiemens/ac6bea1e6c7684d62f544bd79b2182a4

The problem comes after step 4. I was instructed to reboot again after clicking ok.

When the machine reboots, it stucks at the Acer logo and the operating system which is Ubuntu is not able to boot. Following some guide on google, I am able to enter the BIOS and do some configurations. However, it ends up in showing up initramfs command line. I think I have accidentally corrupted the initramfs in the process of signing my kernel.

Initramfs command line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w84q4.jpg

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Acer Swift 5 N19H3. Any idea to wake up my laptop? I need it for my studies.

Comment: From a live USB, what is the output of `blkid`? It looks like Ubuntu is not able to mount the root filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what is a live USB and I don’t know how to use it. Is there a way to restore my data?

Comment: no worries, a live USB is the USB stick you create to install Ubuntu in the first place. It has a 'live system', that is, you can temporarily use Ubuntu off the USB stick without installing anything. Your data should be safe; it's only the Linux kernel that's having issues booting with your changed configuration.

Comment: If you start a live USB, you can open your file system and recover your data if you plan on simply wiping (formatting) the disk. However, we also should be able to resolve the issue it's facing, and so the operating system itself should be recoverable, without needing to reinstall or wipe.

Comment: If you'd like some help, we can go ahead and create a chat room on StackOverflow (where you have enough reputation to enter a chat), and I can walk you through some troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Yeah that is great, please let me know what shall I do next

Comment: Try [this link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128405/discussion-between-galexite-and-jun-cheng)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion in chat, we determined that your system firmware's SATA mode was reset to 'Optane without RAID'. Linux does not seem to be compatible with this configuration, and even a live system was not able to detect the internal SSD.

To resolve the issue, set your `SATA Mode` to `AHCI` in your system firmware (BIOS) setup menu, and Ubuntu boots fine.