# allocating 1 pages for mok config table failed: not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, display-resolution

i am running ubuntu 20.04.6 since a regular update a few weeks ago, in which the boot process was also processed, i get the following error message in the early boot screen: "allocating 1 pages for mok config table failed: not found". since then the boot screen of grub is only in the lowest resolution. Even when I try to boot my second partition with Windows. I only get a 1280x800 screen resolution there and I can't change it back to 1920x1080. there is no option for anymore. please, how can i fix this?

Comment: this question is similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357061/ubuntu-is-unable-to-boot-after-enroll-mok-error-message-efi-mok-var-config-tab The MOK table is a stratagem to pass information from firmware to the kernel. Try reverting to a previous kernel if any is still available as an option in grub.

Comment: @devnull - thanks for help. but i don't know how to do it. i'm a newbie. is there any chance, that upcoming updates will fix this?